# What's wrong with my coding? 'AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter fourcc''

Tags: python, opencv

I'm Jeong Won Kyoung. I have a serious question to you.
When coding like this, I have warning message like this.

coding:

```
#coding utf-8
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('X','V','I','D')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fource, 20, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        #write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break

#release everything if job is finishing
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

And then I ran the module, I got this weird result.

"Traceback (most recent call last)
File"/home/pi/saving_a_video.py", line.8,in <module>
     fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D') 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter fourcc"
has appeared on other python window.
```

I just followed this coding from 
"http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html" and then, it didn't work well.
How can I change this coding 'fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')'?
How can I operate this program???

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc` instead of `cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc`

Comment: well. Although I changed to cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc , it didn't operate well.

Comment: Did the exception change?